# I need to open an excel worksheet while closing an power point application

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

If some one is going to update the power point they also need to update the excel sheet how to make this happen? 
I am sure it can be done through macro but i am not good with it.kindly help me out...

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim strFile As String
Dim WB As Workbook
If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then
Dim DirFile As String
DirFile = "C:\Users\tg2412\Documents\1.xlsx"
If Len(Dir(DirFile)) = 0 Then
  MsgBox "File does not exist"
Else
 Set WB = Workbooks.Open(DirFile)
 End If    
   End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance...:)

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: i need  to open excel document while closing a powerpoint application the above code can be used in excel how to use it in power point

Answer (score 0):

You need two things:

### Event handling:

Your powerpoint needs to handle the presentation close event unless you intend to close it programatically. If so, skip to the next heading. Powerpoint events are not as straightforward as Excel's. Here's a place to start with:

http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00004_Make_your_VBA_code_in_PowerPoint_respond_to_events.htm

### Excel Application object:

Use Excel application object to launch Excel from Powerpoint:

```
Dim Excel As Object
Dim Workbook As Object
Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Excel.Visible = True 'Set this to false if you want Excel to work in the background
'Add more code to verify the path with dir()
Set Workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Open("YourPathHere", True, False)
```

Comment: is there any way to open excel with out add-in installation

Comment: The code snippet in the answer would open excel from Powerpoint, try it.

Comment: i need to execute event with out add in installation or run a macro in power point automatically

Comment: You do not need the addin. Just follow this example from the URL I provided you with http://skp.mvps.org/downloads/pptevent.zip

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-word/how-can-i-assign-or-change-keyboard-shortcuts-to/5ea9ac54-494d-4a09-9104-91ea41f7d305

Comment: the answer is useful for word but there is no shortcut customizer in powerpoint 2013

Comment: can you give me an idea to trap an event such as keyboard event to start an macro